# Function always returns false

Tags: php

I am working on a project that users apply for events. The pertinent code I have now is as follows:

```
      <? if(in_array($u_id, $app)){ ?>
          <td>Unapply:</td>
          <td><a href="event_unapply.php?event_id=<?=$e_id; ?>">Unapply</a></td>
      <? } else{ ?>
           <td>Apply:</td>
           <td><a href="event_apply.php?event_id=<?=$e_id; ?>">Apply!</a></td>
      <? }?>
```

Now if a user is applied, the print_r of the array looks like:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 3 [Userid] => 1 ) )`

$u_id matches the [Userid] in the event but it always goes to the else statement.

I tried doing `$app['0']` but then every time the user is not applied for an event, it returns a PHP error.

Does anyone have an idea to make it so it would work?

Comment: Please don't rely on short open tags, but use proper / sane `<?php` php tags. Thank you, your fellow developers.

Comment: What is the harm in using short tags?

Comment: Mainly portability. And sanity.

Comment: @Matt, [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/200640/417685)

Comment: In all honesty, I have been using short tags for years. I don't plan on changing hosts. The script will never be released. The script will never even be looked at by anyone but me. I chose to use short tags. It's my decision. You chose to use long. That's yours. So if you think I'm 'insane' because I use short tags, then so be it. But downvoting my question just because I don't obide by your 'rules' is childish in my opinion.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nvmd, had a tad of a brain fart but I got it working correctly by using:

```
      <? if($u_id == $app['0']['Userid']){ ?>
          <td>Unapply:</td>
          <td><a href="event_unapply.php?event_id=<?=$e_id; ?>">Unapply</a></td>
      <? } else{ ?>
           <td>Apply:</td>
           <td><a href="event_apply.php?event_id=<?=$e_id; ?>">Apply!</a></td>
      <? }?>
```